# Django and JS for loop: how to change a variable value into {%static 'path' %}?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to find out how to change a path in a picture having **JS** logic in the **Django** template.
As an example - according to logic in the **JS** script - change from:

`hangman_game/img/s0.jpg`
to
`hangman_game/img/s1.jpg`
then to
`hangman_game/img/s2.jpg`
ect

In the previous framework, it was working. But now, I'm migrating a page to the Django framework. Almost all are ready, but **JS for loop** syntax mentioned previously isn't working and I'm looking for a way: how to properly set a for loop that will generate a new path to the picture in the **HTML** file.

in my html file I have:

```
<div id="gallows">
    <img src="{% static 'hangman_game/img/s0.jpg' %}" alt="" />
</div>
```

This part is ok.
The problem is, that this `div` is linked to for loop in js file where I previously had:

```
var errorCount = 0;

if(matched == true)
    {
        
        // errorCount for changing picture:
        errorCount++;
        var picture = "img/s" + errorCount + ".jpg"
        document.getElementById("gallows").innerHTML = '<img src="'+picture+'"alt="" />';
```

Outside Django, it was working, but after migrating to Django it stopped (obviously).

Because **JS** `var picture` is a string, I'm pretty sure that I can use `{% static %}`, but I don't know how.

I tried to update the **JS** file in several ways (without a success). In other words changing this part:
[image]
to:

```
var picture = "{% static 'hangman_game/img/s" + errorCount + ".jpg' %}"
```

```
var picture = "{% static 'hangman_game/img/s' %}{{errorCount+ .jpg}}"
```

```
var picture = "{% static 'hangman_game/img/s' %}{{errorCount+ '.jpg'}}"
```

```
var picture = "{% static 'hangman_game/img/s' %}{{+errorCount+ '.jpg'}}"
```

```
var picture = "{% static 'hangman_game/img/s' %}+errorCount+{{'.jpg'}}"
```

```
var picture = "{% static 'hangman_game/img/s' %}+errorCount+{{.jpg}}"
```

How to implement a proper `{% static %}` template tag in this for loop?

Comment: Django template tag like {% static %} are executed on backend before browser get html page.  this tag (static) is for manaing static files. If tag   <img src="{% static 'hangman_game/img/s0.jpg' %}" alt="" /> works just inspect this rendred fragment to see what is generated path/to/img and then use it as your picture char.

Comment: You must write your own logic to generate path or use AJAX views for sending paths in `JsonResponse` list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. **Waldemar Podsiadło**: Your suggestion was a good clue. After inspection, I set a path to my server address instead of a path in the Djangos files tree. Now it's working. `var picture = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/hangman_game/img/s" + errorCount + ".jpg"`

**Patryk Szczepański**: is it a better idea to stick to my own logic or dig it with Ajax? Are there any reasons to rather use Ajax as the main tool for such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what mechanism is behind the solution of this problem, but, after inspection, I realized that the page was unable to find a path in the **JS** file verbalized as a typical path. It was expected to have a server address as a root: **`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`**

So, having in the **HTML** file:

```
<div id="gallows">
    <img src="{% static 'hangman_game/img/s0.jpg' %}" alt="" />
</div>
```

I should have had modyfied part `var picture = "img/s" + errorCount + ".jpg"`  in the **js** file to:

```
        errorCount++;
        // var picture = "{% static 'hangman_game/img/s" + errorCount + ".jpg' %}"
        
        var picture = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/hangman_game/img/s" + errorCount + ".jpg"
        document.getElementById("gallows").innerHTML = '<img src="'+picture+'"alt="" />';
```

With that, it works.