# Is it possible to invoke sound from the JS file in Django's HTML template without Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I'm in the middle of migrating a site to **Django** framework. Almost all **JS** scripts works, except those related to sound.

I have a play/pause button for a song and some sounds invoked when the mouse is hovering over particular buttons. For just those files I received from the console:

[image]
Of course, those files are in `/static/hangman_game/` folder.

Other static files (js, css) work.
Is it possible to somehow activate those functions related to playing sound/music without **Ajax**?

Function in Django's template html is `onclick="togglePlay()`.

Variables and functions used in **JS** file:

```
var yes = new Audio("yes.wav");
var no = new Audio("no.wav");


var myAudio = new Audio('John Jacob Niles - The Maid Freed From The Gallows (1940).mp3');

function togglePlay() {
  if (isPlaying) {
    myAudio.pause()
  } else {
    myAudio.play();
  }
};
myAudio.onplaying = function() {
  isPlaying = true;
};
myAudio.onpause = function() {
  isPlaying = false;
};

function checkIt(num)
{
    var matched = false;

    for (i=0; i<lengthPass; i++)
    {
        if(pass.charAt(i) == letters[num])
        {
            //// alert(i); //Test
            pass1 = pass1.setCharacter(i, letters[num]);
            matched = true;
        }
    }
    if(matched == true)
    {
        yes.play();
        var element = "let" + num;
        document.getElementById(element).style.background = "#003300";
        document.getElementById(element).style.background = "#00C000";
        document.getElementById(element).style.background = "3px solid #00C000";
        document.getElementById(element).style.background = "default";

        updatePass();
    }
    else
    {
        no.play();
    }
```

Comment: Ajax is not used here

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with files not found (what was encountered in inspection and server's console) is very similar to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73281873/django-and-js-for-loop-how-to-change-a-variable-value-into-static-path/73310209#73310209).
When I migrate the site to Django, all file paths placed in the **JS** file have to have the server address as a root. So when I had for example in **js** file:

```
var yes = new Audio("yes.wav");
var no = new Audio("no.wav");
```

... all that's needed is just add `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` like that:

```
var yes = new Audio("http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/hangman_game/yes.wav");
var no = new Audio("http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/hangman_game/no.wav");
```